# iOS Unrecognized selector sent to instance for call back from modal view

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, unrecognized-selector, performselector

I'm calling:

```
emailDetailView.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                  target:self 
                                                  action:@selector(cancel)];

emailDetailView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(emailAddressSelected:emailAddressReturned:)];

UINavigationController *emailDetailNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:emailDetailView];

[self presentModalViewController:emailDetailNavCon animated:YES] ;
```

And here's my methods referenced as selected:

```
-(void) emailAddressSelected:(NSString *)emailAddressSelectedString {
    NSLog(@"emailAddressSelected is %@", emailAddressSelectedString);
    emailAddressReturned = emailAddressSelectedString;
    [self performSelector:@selector(showMailComposeController)];
}

-(void)cancel {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] 
                                          animated:YES];
}
```

Neither call back from the buttons on the child view (either Cancel or Done) is doing what I expected.

I'm trying to figure out how to have a click on the child modal view Cancel Button close the modal view and show the parent view.

I'm also trying to figure out how to have a click on Done button in the child modal view execute the `emailAddressSelected:(NSString *)emailAddressSelectedString` method.

Right now the call to the `emailAddressSelected:(NSString *)emailAddressSelectedString` method is generating an "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

I've tried numerous variations from previous questions but still get the error or don't get the button actions that I expect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong with your cancel selector, but your done selector is incorrect.  Should be

```
@selector(emailAddressSelected:)
```

But it won't pass a NSString to your method there.  It will pass the sender which in your case is the  UIBarButtonItem.

So that should be

```
    -(void) emailAddressSelected:(UIBarButtonItem * )sender
```

Comment: I need to be able to pass back a parameter with the Done button though. The value is not on the bar button so I don't think that is able to do the trick. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah you won't be able to pass back meta data to your target action.  All you get is the option to pass the UIControl back.   In your target action you will need to pull the data from the UITextField or whatever other widget holds the email address.  Hope that helps?  Make sense?